Application Insights is not capturing SQL commands
Hoping someone can help out.
I have multiple websites running on a VM in Azure. They all access an Azure SQL database.
I have recently configured Application Insight and all things are working apart from capturing the SQL statements.
My websites are a combination of ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET.
I have followed the documents
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#advanced-sql-tracking-to-get-full-sql-query
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/application-insights-asp-net-agent?tabs=api-reference#enable-instrumentationengine
The instrumentation seems to be installed properly and seems to be working but while I get the dependency event I don't get the SQL statement which is being run.
If I query the log using this
dependencies | where success != "True" and type == "SQL" | take 10

I can see failed events but there no reason for the failure.
Looking for any help is trying to find out why the SQL statements aren't being captured or some way of fixing it.
Thanks
Greg


My websites are a combination of ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET.

I have tried to log SQL Dependencies for ASP.Net Framework Application.
Check the below steps:

I have referred this MSDoc and configure Application Insights.

From the MSDoc which you have shared I have added the below command in ApplicationInsights.config file under <TelemetryModules> tag.


<EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation>true</EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation>


Add the SQLDB Connection String in Web.config file.

With the reference from MSDoc Track custom operations with Application Insights .NET SDK, added the below code in Controller class.


public TelemetryClient tl;
public ActionResult Index()
{
    tl = new TelemetryClient();
 
    var conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppInsightsConnection"].ConnectionString;
    var sql = new SqlConnection(conn);
    sql.Open();

    string cmdtxt = "Select * from TestData";
    var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdtxt, sql);

    string dependencyType = "My SQL Server";
    string dependencyName = "SQL Dependency from Framework App";
    var time = DateTimeOffset.Now;

    using (var depend = tl.StartOperation<DependencyTelemetry>(dependencyName))
    {
        depend.Telemetry.Type = dependencyType;
        depend.Telemetry.Data = cmdtxt;
        depend.Telemetry.Success = true;

        var er = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        depend.Telemetry.Duration = DateTimeOffset.Now - time;
    }

    sql.Close();
    return View();
}

Transaction Search:


Check for the dependency Name and click on it.


Logs:


For the deployed Azure App Service, make sure to enable the SQL Commands under App Service => Application Insights.


